# Terraform Import of map resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, dictionary, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've got a map variable that identifies existing s3 buckets:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = var.s3_replication
  bucket   = each.value.source
  #other configuration
}

variable "s3_replication" {
  description = "Map of buckets to replicate"
  type        = map
  default = {
    logs = {
      source = "logs_bucket",
      destination = "central_logs_bucket"
    },
    security = {
      source = "cloudtrail_bucket",
      destination = "central_security_bucket"
    }
  }
}
```

Since these buckets already exist, I am trying to import them and then apply the a configuration to them to update the resources. Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to do a terraform import on these. I've tried:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"] logs_bucket
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket[logs] logs_bucket
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0] logs_bucket
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].source logs_bucket
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0[source]] logs_bucket
```

All failing with a different error. Any idea on how to import existing resources listed on a map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `terraform import` subcommand relies on strings in the map key within resource namespaces that are first class expression, and this causes issues with shell interpreters where the resource is not a first class expression because they are not the Terraform DSL. You can work around this by casting the entire resource name as a literal string:

```
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"]' logs_bucket
```

and this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Does this need to target "source" in a way? Looks like it's still erroring out: 
Error: Invalid expression
  on <value for var.s3_replication> line 1:
  (source code not available)
Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
Error: No value for required variable
  on variables.tf line 18:
  18: variable "s3_replication" {
The root module input variable "s3_replication" is not set, and has no
default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
value for this variable.

Comment: Thanks, your syntax was correct, I just needed the -var-file=path to point to the tfvars file

Answer (score 2):

Before doing an `import` I recommend doing a terraform `plan`. The output of the plan would look like this:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = "private"
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "logs_bucket"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                    = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

      + versioning {
          + enabled    = (known after apply)
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # aws_s3_bucket.bucket["security"] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = "private"
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "cloudtrail_bucket"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                    = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

      + versioning {
          + enabled    = (known after apply)
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Having this plan we can see that the resources which will be created can be references as `aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"]` and `aws_s3_bucket.bucket["security"]`. Instead of doing an `apply` we can import them as follows:

Bash:

```
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket["security"]' cloudtrail-bucket
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"]' logs-bucket
```

Windows CMD:

```
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket[\"security\"]' cloudtrail-bucket
terraform import 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket[\"logs\"]' logs-bucket
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the correct syntax. I just made the mistake of missing the -var-file=path. Adding that fixed the issue

Comment: what to do with zsh terminal ??

Answer (score 1):

The syntax from the answers posted are correct. My code was just bugging out because it couldn't locate the varsfile. I needed to add -var-file={{ path to tfvars }}. So the final syntax looks like:

```
terraform import -var-file={{ path to tfvars}} 'aws_s3_bucket.bucket["logs"]' logs_bucket
```